# Making image appear using *ngIf

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display image one when clicks are < 5. image two when clicks are < 10. Struggling to correctly use *ngIf. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction please?

html

```
  <div class="test" (click) = "testFunction()"> </div>
  <img src="assets/one.jpg">
  <img src="assets/two.png">
  <img src="assets/three.jpg">

  {{clicks}}

  <button (click) = "clearFunction()"> clear! </button>
```

ts

```
 clicks: number = 0;

 testFunction() {
  this.clicks += 1;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? `*ngIf="clicks < 5"` doens't get the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for. When `clicks` is greater than 5 (i.e 6) the image will appear.

```
  <div class="test" (click) = "testFunction()"> </div>
  <img *ngIf="clicks > 5" src="assets/one.jpg">
  <img *ngIf="clicks > 10" src="assets/two.png">
  <img *ngIf="clicks > 15" src="assets/three.jpg">

  {{clicks}}

  <button (click) = "clearFunction()"> clear! </button>
```